# C++ using functions from shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I have the following problem:

I have two separate c++ projects, and want to use certain functions from one of them in the other. I am compiling using g++, on Linux.

I decided to do this by creating a shared library out of the project from which to use the functions. I added -fPIC to the compiler flags in the Makefile and then created a shared library like this:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmyproject.so.1 -o libmyproject.so a.o b.o c.o -lc
```

Then I simply copied the .so file and the header files into the (parent) directory of the new project and added the following to its Makefile:

To LIBS:

```
-L/../external_proj/libmyproject.so
```

To CXXFLAGS:

```
-I/../external_proj
```

Then I #include the appropriate header file in the destination project code and try to call certain functions from the original project. However, when I compile the destination project I get an error "undefined reference" for the imported function.

My question is then: is there something I'm missing in this setup? Is there perhaps something that needs to be added to the headers in the original project in order to export the functions I want to use?

I should note this is the first time I have attempted to use a shared library in this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-L` option only specifies the ***directory*** where the linker will search for libraries to link with. Then you will need to use the `-l` option to specify the base name of the shared library (without the "lib" prefix and the ".so" suffix).

But even that will unlikely to be enough. The runtime loader needs to find the shared library, when you attempt to try to execute it. `-L` and `-l` will be sufficient to successfully link, but the runtime loader only searches `/usr/lib(64)?`, and a few other places by default. It does NOT search the current directory, and the ELF binary only records the names of the shared libraries that must be loaded, and not their full pathnames. You have to explicitly record any extra directories to search for any shared libraries, which is the `-rpath` option.

To finish the job you will also need to pass `-rpath` to the linker, but g++ does not support this option directory, you will have to use `-W` to do that.

The full set of options you will likely need are:

```
-L/../external_proj -lmyproject -Wl,-rpath -Wl,`cd ../external_proj && pwd`
```

See gcc documentation for more information on the `-W` option.

Absolute pathnames should be used with `-rpath`, hence the need to obtain the full pathname to the directory where the shared library is.

Comment: Execute `readelf -a <program> | grep PATH` to see what shared library search path was set for your executable. This will tell you if your rpath was set correctly.

Comment: sorry, deleted my previous comment to try something. The runtime loading issue was solved by moving your full -Wl command from the CXXFLAGS to another variable LDFLAGS. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` flag is to add a *path* to search libraries in. The `-l` (lower-case L) is for linking with a library in the search path.

Or you can skip the flags and link with the library directly, almost like you do now (but without the `-L` option).

---

If you use the `-l` option, then remember that for a file `libname.so` you use only `name` as the library name. As in `-lname`. The linker will search for the correct files with the added prefix and suffix.

---

And lastly an important note about the paths used when linking: If you use `-L` and `-l` to link with a shared library, it's only the linker which will find the library. The OS runtime-loader will *not* be able to see the path used and will not find the library, if it's in a non-standard location. For that you must also set the *runtime-path* using the special linker option `-rpath`.

Unfortunately the GCC frontend program `g++` doesn't recognize that option, you have to use `-Wl` to tell `g++` to pass on an option to the actual linker. As in `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/libraries`.

To summarize, here are the different variants you can use:

- Link directly with the library: `g++ your_source.cpp ../external_proj/libmyproject.so`
- Use the `-L` and `-l` options: `g++ your_source.cpp -L../external_proj -lmyproject`
- To set the runtime linker path: `g++ your_source.cpp -L../external_proj -lmyproject -Wl,-rpath,../external_proj`